# User Id in DropBox SDK

Tags: iphone, dropbox

How can i find the user id of current User who has logined through XCode In DropBox SDK.
I need it done programmatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your code after you've linked, you can add:

```
[self.restClient loadAccountInfo];
```

and the delegate:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo*)info {
    NSLog(@"UserID: %@ %@", [info displayName], [info userId]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you linked to dropbox, you can try the following code:

```
NSString* dropbox_id=[[DBSession sharedSession].userIds objectAtIndex:0];
```