# How to print name of user on the page after authentication process with Dropbox in ios?

Tags: ios, dropbox

I am working with the iOS application in which I have to authenticate the user with Oauth protocol. After the authentication process when I came back to the screen I want to show the user name on the screen.i am trying to use `DBAccountInfo` but not getting succedded.
Please help me to get out of this problem.
Thank You for your precious time.

i am using the below code for that ::

```
DBAccountInfo *info = _manager.linkedAccount.info;
            if (info) {
                text = [text stringByAppendingFormat:@" Mr.%@", info.displayName];
            }
```

Comment: Could you show the code when you try to use `DBAccountInfo`?

Comment: DBAccountInfo *info = _manager.linkedAccount.info;
   if (info) {
    text = [text stringByAppendingFormat:@" Mr.%@", info.displayName];
   }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580415/user-id-in-dropbox-sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say this isn't succeeding, what do you mean? Do you see a nil value for `info` or `info.displayName`? Or do you see some other issue?

Assuming what you're seeing is that the `DBAccountInfo` object isn't populated, it's probably just a timing issue. Everything in the Sync API (which it appears you're using based on the class names) is asynchronous, so after linking, the SDK will call out to Dropbox's servers and fetch the account info. That will take some time (perhaps a second or two), and before that you won't be able to see any account info.

From [the documentation on `DBAccount.info`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBAccount.info):

> Information about the user of this account, or nil if no info is
>   available. Account info is fetched in the background. To be notified
>   when account info is available or updated, use
>   [`addObserver:block:`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBAccount.addObserver%3ablock%3a).

So you'll need to add an observer and wait for the account info to be populated.